# Downloading Mp3 using Python in Windows mangles the song however in Linux it doesn't

Tags: python, httpwebrequest, mp3, web-scraping

I've setup a script to download an mp3 using urllib2 in Python.

```
url = 'example.com'
req2 = urllib2.Request(url)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req2)

#grab the data
data = response.read()

mp3Name = "song.mp3"
song = open(mp3Name, "w")
song.write(data)    # was data2
song.close()
```

Turns out it was somehow related to me downloading it on Windows or my current Python version. I tested the code on my Ubuntu distro and the mp3 file downloaded perfectly fine... So I just used the simple `urllib2.openurl` method and it worked perfect!

To summarize:

- I am using `urllib2.openurl` in Python on an Ubuntu distro.
- I am using a newer version of Python but I feel like it can't be that.
- The mp3 are encoded in LAME.

Does anyone have any clue what was causing the weird issue running the code on my Windows box? I wonder why downloading on Windows mangled the mp3?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try binary file mode. `open(mp3Name, "wb")`
You're probably getting line ending translations.

The file is binary, yes. It's the mode that wasn't. When a file is opened, it can be set to read as a text file (this is default). When it does this, it will convert line endings to match the platform. On Windows, line ends are `\r\n` In most other places it's either `\r` or `\n`. This change messes up the data stream.

Comment: dang crazy! I thought it was already binary otherwise it wouldn't sorta play. I thought it was on by default!

Comment: @Setheron: I added a bit of detail to the answer.