# Using dart to download a file

Tags: dart

Can we use `dart` to download a file?

For example in [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3878882/downloading-mp3-using-python-in-windows-mangles-the-song-however-in-linux-it-doe)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

[Shailen's response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18033791/634863) is correct and can even be a little shorter with [Stream.pipe](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_async/Stream.html#pipe).

```dart
import 'dart:io';

main() async {
  final request = await HttpClient().getUrl(Uri.parse('http://example.com'));
  final response = await request.close();
  response.pipe(File('foo.txt').openWrite());
}
```

Comment: Doing this in a for loop would start all the downloads in parallel. How to serialize that?

Comment: there is a memory leak in your example, the HttpClient is never closed. You must call `httpClient.close();` (The Shailen's response does) to avoid keeping the connection alive after the response.

Answer (score 35):

I'm using the [HTTP](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/http) package a lot. If you want to download a file that is not huge, you could use the HTTP package for a cleaner approach:

```dart
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

main() {
  http.get(url).then((response) {
    new File(path).writeAsBytes(response.bodyBytes);
  });
}
```

What Alexandre wrote will perform better for larger files. Consider writing a helper function for that if you find the need for downloading files often.

Comment: Doing this in a for loop would start all the downloads in parallel. How to serialize that?

Comment: @PhaniRithvij You would just add another `.then` at the end. It's a lot cleaner if you use await instead, though.

Comment: is it tested in iOS also??

Answer (score 3):

The python example linked to in the question involves requesting the contents of `example.com` and writing the response to a file.

Here is how you can do something similar in Dart:

```dart
import 'dart:io';

main() {
  var url = Uri.parse('http://example.com');
  var httpClient = new HttpClient();
  httpClient.getUrl(url)
    .then((HttpClientRequest request) {
      return request.close();
    })
    .then((HttpClientResponse response) {
      response.transform(new StringDecoder()).toList().then((data) {
        var body = data.join('');
        print(body);
        var file = new File('foo.txt');
        file.writeAsString(body).then((_) {
          httpClient.close();
        });
      });
    });
}
```

Comment: Ok so that's doable, but how about if the content is an image? Thank you.

Comment: Is the Dart API can not be shorter? `new HttpClient()` => `getUrl()` => `close()` => `transform()` => `new StringDecoder()` => `toList()` => `close()`. And this is without taking into account the 4 calls `then()`.

Comment: Please note that the `StringDecoder` class has been replaced by `UTF8.decoder` in recent versions of Dart.

Answer (score 3):

We can use `http.readBytes(url)`.

```dart
await File(path).writeAsBytes(await http.readBytes('https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, first of all you have to request to file url using http dart library like:

```
Response response = await get(Uri.parse(link));
```

after that your Response object (response) will get that file in self and you can simply write the response bytes to a file and that file will be your downloaded file.
as I open file like this:

```
File file = File('image.jpg')
```

then we have to send response bytes to this file like this:

```
file.writeAsBytes(response.bodyBytes);
```

now you have downloaded a image file successfully.. Congrates.

additional, for example let me show you a sample code to download a image file :

```dart
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:http/http.dart';
void main(List<String> args) async {
    var link =
      "https://pps.whatsapp.net/v/t61.24694- 
  24/72779382_449683642563635_3243701117464346624_n.jpg?ccb=11- 
    4&oh=23e3bc2ce3f4940a70cb464494bbda76&oe=619B3B8C";

    Response response = await get(Uri.parse(link));
    File file = File('image.jpg');
    file.writeAsBytes(response.bodyBytes);
}
```

look, this is the code and a file named image.jpg is downloaded at bottom in terminal view is our downloaded image.

[image: screen shot]

this is our actual image which we downloaded.

[image: downloaded image]