# Dart HTTPClient Response query

Tags: dart, httpclient, synchronous

I would like to make the below functionality synchronous. The "onDataLoaded" needs to be called once the stream has been read completely. Please suggest what changes needs to be done.

```dart
String JsonContent="";

new HttpClient().getUrl(Uri.parse(uri))
  .then((HttpClientRequest request) 
   {
      request.headers.removeAll(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT_ENCODING);          
      return request.close();
   })
  .then((HttpClientResponse response) 
   {   
      response.transform(UTF8.decoder).listen((contents) {
        JsonContent = contents.toString();  
        print(JsonContent);
        //onDataLoaded(JsonContent); 
      });          
   });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this should work

```dart
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:convert' show UTF8;

void main(args) {
String JsonContent="";

new HttpClient().getUrl(Uri.parse(uri))
  .then((HttpClientRequest request)
   {
      request.headers.removeAll(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT_ENCODING);
      return request.close();
   })
  .then((HttpClientResponse response)
   {
      response.transform(UTF8.decoder).listen((contents) {
        JsonContent = contents.toString();
        print(JsonContent);
        //onDataLoaded(JsonContent);
      }, onDone: () => onDataLoaded(JsonContent));
   });

}

void onDataLoaded(String jsonContent) {
  print(jsonContent);
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to let onDataLoaded execute first before terminating from the main(args).

Comment: I saw that in your question but wasn't sure if you really meant it because the other part said you want to call `onDataLoaded` when retrieving is done. No, I haven't found a sync version of `getUrl` for the server.
The client has `request.open("GET", url, async : false);` 
See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18404489

Comment: Tried that piece of code before posting my query. Same behaviour - main() terminates and then the content is printed.

Comment: Async execution is putting the closure in the event queue and when the current thread of execution (main) is done, the next item in the queue (getUrl) is executed.